# How to serve two ASP.Net MVC applications on the same IIS Express instance?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-express

I have two ASP.Net MVC applications, let's say **Site1** and **Site2**.

For now, I can successfully access **Site1** by visiting `http://localhost/`

Here's my IIS Express *applicationhost.config* file:

```
<sites>
   <site name="Site1" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
       <application path="/">
           <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%IIS_USER_HOME%\wwwroot\Site1" />
       </application>
       <bindings>
           <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":80:localhost" />
           <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":80:10.49.0.137" />
       </bindings>
   </site>
   <siteDefaults>
       <logFile logFormat="W3C" directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\logs" />
       <traceFailedRequestsLogging directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\logs\tracelogfiles" enabled="false" maxLogFileSizeKB="1024" />
   </siteDefaults>
   <applicationDefaults applicationPool="IISExpressAppPool" />
   <virtualDirectoryDefaults allowSubDirConfig="true" />
</sites>
```

What I want now is:

- Access **Site1** on `http://localhost/Site1`
- Place **Site2** on `%IIS_USER_HOME%\wwwroot\Site2`
- Access **Site2** on `http.//localhost/Site2`

How should I change the above *applicationhost.config* to achieve what I want?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change your applicationhost.config as shown below and restart IIS Express.

```
<sites>    
  <site name="Site1" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
   <application path="/">            
      <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%IIS_USER_HOME%\wwwroot\" />
   </application>        
   <application path="/site1">            
      <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%IIS_USER_HOME%\wwwroot\Site1" />
   </application>        
   <application path="/site2">            
      <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%IIS_USER_HOME%\wwwroot\Site2" />
   </application>        
   <bindings>            
     <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":80:localhost" />            
     <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":80:10.49.0.137" />        
   </bindings>    
  </site>    
  <siteDefaults>        
    <logFile logFormat="W3C" directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\logs" />        
    <traceFailedRequestsLogging directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\logs\tracelogfiles" enabled="false" maxLogFileSizeKB="1024" />    
  </siteDefaults>    
  <applicationDefaults applicationPool="IISExpressAppPool" />    
  <virtualDirectoryDefaults allowSubDirConfig="true" /> 
</sites>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this great entry.

[Working with SSL at Development Time is easier with IISExpress - Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx)

Execute netsh command after applicationHost.config append binding.

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://10.49.0.137:80/ user=everyone
```